# Интернет через proxy не работает в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поставил 32-битную версию на 32 битную винду. Интернет через прокси. В настройках прокси сайты успешно пингует. В логе разобраться не могу.

Лог прикрепляю. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Re54hZpthsT0YyUHhjTnhJM3c/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо задать настройки прокси в файле gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=my.company.domain
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=username
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password

systemProp.https.proxyHost=my.company.domain
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=username
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
```

Но даже это не гарантирует корректность работы. Если у вас стоит Windows прокси типа *ForeFront/ISA* - у меня для вас плохие новости...